# Instant Run detected that you are running on a target device ... multiple user accounts

Tags: android, android-studio

I used to get this error in AndroidStudio 3.1.1 I guess it is because of multiple users on my phone, although I did'nt create a second one it looks like the product "Secure Folder" created one.
If do the following command I get 2 users listed. Is there any chance to get instant run working with 2 users on the device ?

*adb shell pm list users*

Users:

UserInfo{0:Anton:13} running

UserInfo{150:Secure Folder:51020030} running